# comparing 2 dates in js using map.has

Tags: javascript, date, dictionary

I'm using javascripts's '.has' map method to check if a map has a date key. The console.log should return true but returns false.

http://codepen.io/BradLee/pen/bZWrwx?editors=1010

```
var map = new Map();

let data = {
    "Fri Jun 17 2016" : {
        "foo" : "blah"
    },
    "Sun Jun 26 2016" : {
        "foo" : "blah"
    },
    "Wed May 11 2016" : {
        "foo" : "blah"
    }
};

for (let dateString of Object.keys(data)) {
    let date = new Date(dateString);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    map.set(date, "blah");
}

let date = new Date("Fri Jun 17 2016");
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

console.log(map.has(date));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javascript Maps are very underwhelming and actually work like identity Maps, that is, keys are simply compared with ===, not with some smart, potentially user-defined equality function or hash.

That doesn't work in your case because all your dates have different references.

To achieve what you want, I'm afraid you would have to store and compare the timestamp instead (which is a number, so === will have the proper behavior you're looking for). It will even work with plain objects, as the number will get toString'ed but the comparison will still work.
Maybe even better, storing the date straight away in an object will toString() it, and it will actually work:

```
var map = {}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u9m9vspq/

Comment: A little over 2 years later, has this changed? I figured the only reasonable explanation for my `Map<Date, Number>` returning undefined was that two equivalent Date objects don't evaluate as equal. Back to the ol' `{}` standard I guess.